# How do I create Amazon CloudWatch Metric Filter & Alarm Using AWS CDK and Python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, cloudwatch-alarms

I am a beginner with CDK and I want to create a metric filter and alarm using CDK and Python to use them on the logs of my EC2 instance that are pushed to CloudWatch.

Did anyone implement this before?

Thanks!

Comment: I saw the documentation before I asked the question. My problem is how I can specify the log data in which I want to apply the filter. I have the log group that contains my ec2 instances logs and I know how to create a metric filter and the alarm, but I am not able to point on my log group to specify that I just need to filter this log I have in cloudwatch and not all logs I have, and without creating a new log group.

Comment: I have many ec2 instances, each one send his logs to the same log group in cloud watch. Now I want to apply a filter on that log group to detect authentication errors.

Comment: PYou should add that to the  question. You would filter the message with the filter pattern you provide. If all instances send the same log message without any identifying info in the message, it'll be impossible to tell them apart. Metric filters don't provide a way to filter based on stream names.

Comment: Okay, Thanks I got it so if all my ec2 instances send their logs to the same log group in cloudwatch I won't be possible to filter them apart. Please can you tell if there is any way to apply the filter on multiple ec2 logs and how I should push those logs to make it possible

Comment: The Metric filter is applied to all logs in the log group.

Comment: Yes, that's true. There is no way to apply the filtre in the Stream log on a log group.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to start by looking at the CDK documentation.

Metric filters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.MetricFilter.html

Alarms: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Alarm.html

Answer (score -1):

we can't apply Metric filter on log stream it work diractly on log group. To be able to get the info needed from your Event log you can use Subsctiption filter. Thanks :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).